# Searching portable C/++ COM-port library, freely licensed

Tags: serial-port, portability

As title says, I've been trying to find a portable library with C/++ bindings for doing basic COM-port communication for an application I'm servicing. Windows/Linux support is a minimum.

As I'm not the original author of the software, and I'm not allowed to alter the details of the contract, the library has to be licensed so that I will be able to freely give back the resulting product without having anyone's hands tied down regarding the nature of the source code (ie. GPL is a no-go, but LGPL, BSD, ZLIB etc. are fine).

Any advices? Or would it perhaps be best to go about this by just writing the two separate Windows/Linux parts myself?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Boost C++ Libraries have [portable serial port support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html). They have a non-GPL [free license](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a serial library that is BSD licensed and has been tested on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

http://wjwwood.github.com/serial/